# Cakephp Containable not working at all

Tags: cakephp, containable

I have been banging my head on the wall over this. I have a model Sku that belongs to model Purchase. My AppModel has `$actAs=array('Containable') and $recursive=-1`

Inside SkuController, when I do `$this->Sku->find('all', array('contain' => 'Purchase'));` I don't get Purchase. I have searched many old questions here and elsewhere on Internet but just can't seem to resolve this. To check if Containable behavior is being loaded, I edited ContainableBehavior.php in lib\Cake\Model\Behavior to make it an invalid php file but that didn't produce any errors. What the heck is wrong!!

Here's the SQL from debug:

> SELECT `Sku`.`id`, `Sku`.`purchase_id`, `Sku`.`item_id`, `Sku`.`upc`,
>   `Sku`.`quantity_avail`, `Sku`.`per_unit_price_amt`,
>   `Sku`.`do_not_delete`, `Sku`.`created`, `Sku`.`modified`,
>   (concat('SK',lpad(`Sku`.`id`,8,'0'))) AS `Sku__idFormatted` FROM
>   `sellble`.`skus` AS `Sku` WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `Sku`.`id` desc

CakePHP ver: 2.4.4

Comment: Is Sku model associated with Purchase?

Comment: Are you using `actAs` or the proper `actsAs` variable?  Are your variable assignments public, i.e. `public $actsAs = array('Containable');`?  If you remove the recursive setting, does the purchase data return in your find (just to check the association)?  If you create a reflection of your model, does it carry the array containing 'Containable' in the actsAs variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is different across versions but I have always specified the contain within an array and that works fine for me.

```
$this->Sku->find('all', array('contain' => array('Purchase')));
```

Or for mapping only the fields or conditions you want:

```
$this->Sku->find('all',
     array('contain' => array(
         'Purchase' => array(
             'fields' => Purchase.name
             'conditions' => array(
                  Purchase.name = 'somename'
                  )
             )
         )
     )
);
```

Comment: tried both but it didn't help.. i just think the ContainableBehavior is not even being loaded

Comment: There's a typo in your $actAs, which should be $actsAs. Otherwise your configuration looks exactly like mine so sorry can't help much further on why it isn't loading.

Comment: Oh my god!! I must be blind.. Ty Ty Ty.. So ashamed to see that stupid mistake, and of course it's these lame mistakes that make programmer's life miserable.. Ty again